# How to get a labels value in Selenium Chrome Driver using C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am making a bot that list all the given assembled letters to make the players connect or build a word around that given value of assembled letters, im very new to selenium and still grasping the best practices thanks in advance. (https://jklm.fun "BombParty")
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGyMd.png

> **What we want to achieve:**
>
> ---
>
> *//locate the element (the one the center of that bomb)*
>
> ---
>
> *//extract the elements displayed value (the label)*
>
> ---
>
> *//Console Log that value*

> **My Code:**
>
> ```
>             ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); //creating chrome driver options to add some commands to remove the message "This is automated . . ."
>             options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", true);
>             options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
>             options.AddArgument("window-size=1200x600");
>
>
>             var driver = new ChromeDriver(options); //declear our driver for us to automate and control
>
>
>             driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://jklm.fun/QVVC"); // go to our targeted uri
>
>             driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25); // wait for sometime to give our client to load
> ```
>
> // let our user enter the username or join a game
>
> ```
>             while (true) // loop our funtion to locate and extract the given word
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.syllable")); //we did a FindElements because the label can change value over time and state another syllable
>                     Console.WriteLine("Success!");
>                 }
>                 catch
>                 {
>                     Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
>                 }
>             }
> ```

> **The Output of my Code:**
> Success!

> **What I Have tried:**
>
> ```
>                 var word = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.syllable"));
>                 Console.WriteLine(word.Text.ToString());
> ```
>
> **The Result:** Failed!

> **Update:**
> So i tried to get the value after it finds it and i will find it again,it was a success but it only returns this string, how to fix this?
> [The update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaOtb.png)

Comment: How exactly did it fail?  Did you get an error?

Comment: it was unable to locate the xpath , css selector div.syllable

Comment: Pretty common error with selenium.  You need to fix your selector so that it actually selects the element that you want.

Comment: without the ExceptionHandler on the "What I Have Tried"

Comment: It works perfectly fine just with the driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.syllable"));

Comment: but when you try to make it a variable at disposal it gives of the error unable to locate . . .

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Maybe you should include the code that does that.

Comment: when i try to use the function like this
var word = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.syllable"));
it fails instantly throwing the error message Unable to locate xpath, css selector

Comment: but when i directly state the funtion driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.syllable")); it works fine and is able to locate the element

Comment: Isn't what you're trying to access contained within the HTML canvas? If so, there wouldn't be an available XPATH/css selector path...

Comment: Add the exception in the question

Comment: im confused what exactly are you guys trying to propose?
maybe show a example on the given problem?